# Databases for sequences indexed by partitions

Tags: co.combinatorics, partitions, integer-sequences, online-resources

Is there a database for sequences indexed by partitions similar to Sloane's OEIS? I mean, I am aware that in the OEIS there are some arrays indexed by partitions, but I feel as though most of such sequences that frequently appear in combinatorial literature are not there.

One example of a sequence I'd really like to recognise begins as follows:

$a[1]=1$,

$a[2]=a[1^2]=2$,

$a[3]=a[1^3]=4$, $a[2,1]=8$,

$a[4]=a[1^4]=8$, $a[3,1]=a[2,1^2]=16$, $a[2^2]=24$,

$a[5]=a[1^5]=16$, $a[4,1]=a[2,1^3]=32$, $a[3,2]=a[2^2,1]=52$, $a[3,1^2]=48$.

The obvious patterns $a[\lambda]=a[\lambda^t]$ and $a[n]=2^{n-1}$, $a[n-1,1]=2^n$ do hold in general, if it helps.

Comment: Obviously, you are very welcome to contribute your favourite statistics - send me/us a message as well if you have any questions/suggestions/remarks!

Comment: "but I feel as though most of such sequences that frequently appear in combinatorial literature are not there" actually holds as well for our project, but we made is as simple as possible to change it!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks for asking this question! It really is a perfect occation for me advertising (once again) the combinatorial statistic finder http://www.FindStat.org!

To search the database for partitions, see http://www.FindStat.org/StatisticFinder/IntegerPartitions

Comment: Thanks a lot Christian, this looks nice. Pity my statistics isn't there :-)

Comment: You can easily go and change that, so the next person searching for it has more luck.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen Christian Stump here on mathoverflow advertising

http://www.findstat.org/

However, your particular statistic does not appear to be in the database yet.

Comment: So such advertisements seem to make sense :-), thanks for posting!